# Read an array of arrays in json file when I run a collection postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I don't know what to write in the param value in the body using postman to read data from a json file, when the jsonfile has an array of arrays like you can see:

I have a json file with this information
[image]

In the request body I write that value for the array keyValue and SectionKeyValue
[image]

In the request body I sent that, What I should to write in the param to read an array of arrays? try to parse these object that you see in the picture:
[image]

thank you!

Comment: In the pre-request could you add `pm.variables.set("convertedKeyValue", JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.get("KeyValue")))` and use `{{convertedKeyValue}}` in place of the `{{Key Value}}`?

Comment: Thank you it was helpful !!